# date format in admin form magento 2

Tags: date, datepicker, magento2.4.2-p2

In the db_schema :

```
 <column name="holidays_start_date" nullable="true" xsi:type="date"  comment="holidays_start_date"/>
```

I created a field of type date in an admin form  :

```
      <field name="holidays_start_date"  sortOrder="3">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Start holidays Date</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">vendor</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">holidays_start_date</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
 <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

When for example i choose the 22 of august 2022, , when i want to save the form , i have got this error :

> main.CRITICAL: Exception message: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to
> parse time string (26/08/2022) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character

But when I use a date like the first of the august 2022, it works.

Could you help me please? I dont know how to change the date format . :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
<field name="display_from" sortOrder="60" formElement="date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Display From</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">hotdeal</item>
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">hh:mm</item>
                <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="minDate" xsi:type="string">new Date()</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
        </validation>
        <dataType>timestamp</dataType>
        <dataScope>display_from</dataScope>
        <label translate="true">From</label>
    </settings>
</field>
```

For db schema

```
<column xsi:type="timestamp" name="display_from" comment="From Time"/>
```

For Only date you can use this :

```
<form>
    ...
    <fieldset>
        ...
        <field name="date_example" formElement="date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">some_source</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Date Example</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <dataScope>some_scope</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
        ...
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Tahnks for your help but i want a date and not a datetime :(

Comment: This may help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217353/magento-2-how-should-i-display-only-date-in-grid

Comment: I updated the answer you can check

Comment: If this helps you a little bit, please mark this an answer

Comment: Hi , rana Zain , it still doesn t work :(    Exception message: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (30/11/2022) when i use your solution.

Comment: Can you please share the logs so, I can check

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer but it s not logical at all :
If i put :

```
        <column name="holidays_start_date" nullable="true" xsi:type="date"  comment="holidays_start_date"/>
```

And

```
  <field name="holidays_start_date" sortOrder="60" formElement="date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">holidays_start_date</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">vendor</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                        <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">hh:mm</item>
                        <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="minDate" xsi:type="string">new Date()</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

It works
But i set at false :
`<item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>`
It does not work anymore . really strange !

Comment: It its helps you can mark this an answer

Comment: Now its working or not